# How to create table with one field with multiple entries? MySQL PhpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

My table goes like this.

```
IDNumber     TransactionNumber
09-2345-21        1101
09-2345-21        2301
09-2345-21        5023
10-1934-23        3924
10-1934-23        7642
```

But I want to make it like this:

```
IDNumber      TransactionNumber
09-2345-21         1101
                   2301
                   5023
10-1934-23         3924
                   7642
```

Thanks!

Comment: That is not how relational databases are meant to be used. You should always have all references of a row specified in an explicit manner, not implicit by position in the table, as you do. Actually most relational database management system won't guarantee a specific position in a table... Instead you perform such layout tasks as you want to on the level of an application using the database as a backend.

Comment: what is IDNumber? i  guess for the better tracking you should repeat the id number and transaction id.

Comment: IDNumber is the one who made a transactions. Let's say One person made a lot of transactions... how could I perform that on database?

Those two are foreign keys... I have 2 tables. 1) for User (where I get the IDNumber) and 2) for TransactionsTable(where I get the TransactionNumber).

Comment: Make it with two table? Or concat all `TransactionNumber` separated by something in one record?